# Approach for improving runtime of Python function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, geopandas

I have a function that relies on a dictionary to identify the files it needs to read and the variable names they're linked to. The function then reads the file, calculates the outputs (in this case a mean value) and returns it as a column in an existing dataframe. This all works well when the files are different, but I have a few cases where I have different variables that are linked to the same file. The function calculates some zonal stats for a Geopandas df.

Is there a more efficient way of going about how I read the files? At the moment the function reads the same file multiple times and calculates the same values, but saves them under a different column name. It's proving to be quite inefficient in terms of time.

```
# The data dictionary has a structure like the one below. Sometimes there are 4-5 variables linked to the same file.
FILEPATH = {"variable_1": "path/commonfile.tif",
            "variable_2": "path/commonfile.tif",
            "variable_3": "path/commonfile.tif",
            "variable_4": "path/otherfile1.tif",
            "variable_5": "path/someotherfile1.tif"}

# my function is like the one below
for variable, filename in FILEPATH.items():
      my_df.loc[:, f'{variable}'] = myfunction(df=my_df, file=f'{filename}', stats_list = ['mean'])
```

Comment: Would reorganizing your dictionary with keys of paths and values of lists of variables help?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help much, I tried reorganising the dictionary using the file  path as key and passing the variables as a list for each file.  The difference in processing time was insignificant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve the runtime of your Python code would be to read the `.tif` files prior to calling `myfunction` and modifying it to expect the `.tif` object that represents the file path. This way you can read each file once and avoid having to re-read it over and over again.

Here's an example on how you could achieve this:

```py
import time
from typing import Dict

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

start_time = time.time()

# The data dictionary has a structure like the one below.
# Sometimes there are 4-5 variables linked to the same file.
FILEPATHS = {
    "variable_0": "/some/path/example_tiff2.tiff",
    "variable_1": "/some/path/example_tiff3.tiff",
    "variable_2": "/some/path/example_tiff3.tiff",
    "variable_3": "/some/path/example_tiff2.tiff",
    "variable_4": "/some/path/example_tiff3.tiff",
    "variable_5": "/some/path/example_tiff3.tiff",
    "variable_6": "/some/path/example_tiff.tiff",
}


def transform_filepaths(filepaths: Dict[str, str]) -> Dict[str, np.array]:
    """
    Transforms a dictionary of `filepaths` to a dictionary of numpy arrays.

    Function reads all the different filepaths once, and then replaces each
    variable's filepath with their corresponding numpy array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filepaths : Dict[str, str]
        Dictionary that contains each variable's filepath.

    Returns
    -------
    Dict[str, np.array]
        Dictionary that contains each variable's numpy array representation
        of the TIFF file.
    """
    tiff_arrays_dict = {
        filepath: np.array(Image.open(filepath)) for filepath in set(filepaths.values())
    }
    return {
        variable_name: tiff_arrays_dict[filepath]
        for variable_name, filepath in filepaths.items()
    }


def myfunction(df: pd.DataFrame, tiff_array: np.array, stats_list=None):
    """Function with the same logic as before, but now it expects a numpy array
    instead of a filepath to then read the TIFF file.
    """
    # do stuff with the tiff_array
    return [tiff_array] * df.shape[0]


# == Create some dummy data ====================================================
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"variable_1": [1, 2, 3], "variable_2": [4, 5, 6]})

# == Transform the filepaths to numpy arrays ===================================
filepaths = transform_filepaths(FILEPATHS)

# == Apply the function ========================================================
for variable, tiff_object in filepaths.items():
    # Instead of passing the filepath, we pass the numpy array
    # therefore we don't need to read the TIFF file multiple times.
    my_df.loc[:, f"{variable}"] = myfunction(my_df, tiff_object, stats_list=["mean"])

print(f"Took: {time.time() - start_time:.2f}s")
# Original implementation: 6.69s
# New implementation: 0.42s
```

In the above code, we defined a new function called `transform_filepaths`. This function is responsible for reading each distinct file defined inside `FILEPATHS` once and generating a new dictionary that maps the variable name and the loaded object. In order to use this newly generated dictionary, you'll have to also modify `myfunction`, so that it expects the loaded object instead of a string with the file location.